# Loading a name based on Value from Parent Component Dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a Parent Component which certain props such as name, queryValue and image to my Child Component which is a Custom Dropdown where as of now i am displaying the names based on a condition check for the default display in the dropdown, but now more data will be shown along with flags. I need to show the name based on the value from the parent .

Parent.jsx

```
<SelectCountry
 options={[
                    {
                        name: 'English (USA)',
                        queryValue: 'en',
                        flagIcon: USA,
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Bahasa Indonesia',
                        queryValue: 'id',
                        flagIcon: ID,
                    },
                ]}
value={localStorage.getItem('locale')} />
```

SelectCountry.jsx

```
<div className={`${baseClassName}__selected-flag-container`}>
     <img 
        src={require(value === "en" ? '../../assets/USA.svg' : '../../assets/indonesia.svg')} 
        alt='desc' 
      /> 
     {value === "en" ? options[0].name : options[1].name}
</div>


//COde for the Custom DropDown will be here
```

As above, HAve put the condition check and its working since there were only two languages, now when more languages are added, not sure how to pick the name and also setting the src in img tag dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all in a bit of wrong way your `Parent.jsx` is the container component so it should hold all your logic so why not pass the appropriate data.

```
<SelectCountry
  options={[
    {
      name: 'English (USA)',
      queryValue: 'en',
      flagIcon: USA,
      src: '../../assets/USA.svg'
    },
    {
      name: 'Bahasa Indonesia',
      queryValue: 'id',
      flagIcon: ID,
      src: '../../assets/indonesia.svg'
    },
  ]}
  value={localStorage.getItem('locale')}
/>
```

& in your presentation component `SelectCountry.jsx` you just present.

const { options } = require('joi');

```
options.map((option) => {
  <div className={`${baseClassName}__selected-flag-container`}>
    <img src={option.src} alt='desc' />
    {option.name}
  </div>;
});
```

I haven't tested so you might need to adjust the code. **[Dan](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov)** has some fantastic free courses on Redux where he teaches more about container & presentation component you can check it out here https://egghead.io/instructors/dan-abramov. Hope this will help you ️️

Comment: Yes i have put the strings in img just fo timebeing, i am getting the image from flagIcon & to list all the options i am doing the same way as suggested by you. But we need to show initially the selected / active name, which is were the problem arises as i ahve done a condition based only for two languages am=nd same doesnt hold good when more than two languages are present.

Comment: @nishant you have to adjust the code according to your requirement. However if you update the question & show me desired HTML then I might help.